# Why is text not positioned properly within list element?

Tags: html, css, list, text-alignment

This is what the problem looks like:

[image]

Here is the mark up:

```
                    <nav class="padding_bottom">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="selected" href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

And the styling:

```
nav {
    height: 100%;
}

nav li {
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: -4.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav li:nth-child(2), 
nav li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: .25em;
}

nav a {
    color: #dddddd;
}

nav a:hover, .selected {
    color: black;
}
```

I can;t figure out why this is happening.  I've played around wiht a lot of the styling elements to see if anything changed, but the problem persisted.

Comment: Is this online so we can take a look?

Comment: If the problem is the E being too far to the right, you could use `padding-right:5px` under `nav li` to make sure that the text doesn't exceed the background.

Comment: It's caused by the -ve `letter-spacing`, if you remove it then the background color extends as expected. You may just need to add some padding or margin, whichever works best for your situation, to the `<a>` elements. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/SAzH5/)

Comment: @Fiddle Could you put this into an answer? This is what helped me. I just needed some margin adjustments.  Silly me. Nonetheless, I was also hoping to get explanation of why this occurs. So, if you could briefly explain why letter-spacing makes this happen, I'd be further grateful. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelPitluk - Made it an answer for you. I have no explanation as to why. I ran into the same issue not too long ago. I've looked and looked, and found no explanation as to why the container doesn't encompass the text when negative letter-spacing is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MichaelPitluk:

It's caused by the -ve `letter-spacing`, if you remove it then the background color extends as expected. You may just need to add some padding or margin, whichever works best for your situation, to the `<a>` elements.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/SAzH5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this please :

```
nav li {
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: -4.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style:inside none;
    background-color:#CCC;
    display:inline-block;
}
```